# Json File - Getting Json data from PHP file and pass it to a JavaScript variable in an HTML File

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I am creating a Data grid using Jquery.

I have a php file which will fetch the data from a MySQL table, create a json and pass it to an HTML page.

That HTML Page contains the code for parsing the JSON data.

Once I get the data in HTML page, I pass it onto data grid which would display the information.

Now, my question is:
I am not able to read the json data in html file. There might be an issue with the file that is been sent. There might be an issue with code itself.

Is there is method by which I can debug the code. I am using PHPStorm as the IDE for creating this application.

I have created a JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3pm98dot/

HTML:

```
 $(function ()
 {

    var northwindProductsJSON;
    $.getJSON("testFileV0.7.php?callback=",function(data)
    {
         northwindProductsJSON = JSON.parse(data);
    });

    var northWindCategoriesJSON = [
                { "ID": 0, "Name": "Food" },
                { "ID": 1, "Name": "Beverages" },
                { "ID": 2, "Name": "Electronics" }
            ];
    //Formatting for igGrid cells to display igCombo text as opposed to igCombo value
    function formatCategoryCombo(val)
    {
        var i, category;

        for (i = 0; i < northWindCategoriesJSON.length; i++)
        {
            category = northWindCategoriesJSON[i];
            if (category.ID === val)
            {
                val = category.Name;
            }
        }

        return val;
    }
    function showFeedback(elementID, message)
    {
        var selector = '#' + elementID;
        $(selector).stop(true, true).html(message)
                .fadeIn(500).delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
    }
    //Grid Initialization
    $("#gridProducts").igGrid({
        dataSource: northwindProductsJSON,
        autoGenerateColumns: false,
        primaryKey: "ID",
        autoCommit: true,
        width: "100%",
        height: "360px",
        columns: [
            { headerText: "", key: "ID", dataType: "number", width: "8%" },
            { headerText: "Name", key: "Name", dataType: "string", width: "24%" },
            { headerText: "Category", key: "CategoryID", dataType: "number", width: "34%", formatter: formatCategoryCombo }
        ],
        features: [
            {
                name: 'Updating',
                columnSettings: [{
                    //The combo is defined as an editor provider. Combo options are defined under 'editorOptions'.
                    columnKey: "CategoryID",
                    editorType: 'combo',
                    required: true,
                    editorOptions: {
                        mode: "dropdown",
                        dataSource: northWindCategoriesJSON,
                        textKey: "Name",
                        valueKey: "ID"
                    }
                }],
                editRowEnded: function () {
                    //To access the updated igGrid data
                    northwindProductsJSON = $("#gridProducts").igGrid().data().igGrid.dataSourceObject();

                    //Show feedback
                    var message = "The grid's data has been updated...";
                    showFeedback("updatedMessage", message);
                }
            }
        ]
    });
 });
```

PHP File:

```
function test(){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "password";
   $dbname = "northwind";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT firstname FROM employees";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$rows = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $i = 1;
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // echo "{" . "ID" . ":" .  $i . "," . "Name" . ":" . $row["firstname"]. "}" . "<br>";
        $rows[] = array('ID' => $i, 'Name' => $row["firstname"] , 'CategoryID' => "1");
        $i++;
    }
    $callback = (empty($_GET["callback"])) ? 'callback' : $_GET["callback"];
    $callback . '(' . json_encode($rows) . ');';
    //json_encode($rows);
}
else
{
    return "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
}
```

Comment: Try displaying the data return in the console `console.log(data);`  and checking the console for any errors.

Comment: You aren't doing anything with $callback.  Maybe you should echo $callback; or something?

Comment: I tried to display data in the console using console.log(data). There is nothing been displayed in the console as of now. I also tried to echo $callback. Still no data.

Comment: Managed to start debugging. As of now the json is getting created but its not been read in the HTML page.

Comment: You're not printing anything on your PHP file. Uncomment the json_encode and print it. `echo json_encode($rows);`
Ajax request is just getting the content of the URL you are requesting, for example your page only prints `hello world`, even you are doing or returning something in your PHP, AJAX will only get the `hello world`.

Comment: Is it just my lack of PHP knowledge, or is `test()` never called?